# Is there a Javascript plugin for creating a handwriting input box?

Tags: javascript, html, digital-handwritting

I haven't found in my search yet, but I'm looking for a way to capture signatures  in an HTML5 form through handwriting. I would think that the value will be stored as a bitmap like format.

Comment: Keep in mind that tool or software recommendations are off-topic for this site.

Comment: PS: I tried to make one myself but it wasn't working. :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/szimek/signature_pad

Shouldn't be too hard if you want to write a plugin yourself.

Comment: Great! Thanks @Pratyush. I think I can take it from here. Appreciate it.